# how to avoid query inside for loop

Tags: query

```
 for(EmailMessage message : Messg){
   System.debug('#####TEST SUBSTRING START #####'+message.Subject);
   try {
      c=[SELECT id,RecordType.name, Description, AccountId, ContactId, OwnerId, CaseNumber, RecordTypeId, CountryCase__c, status, Origin, Subject, VIN__c, Device_Brand__c, Device_Type__c, Language__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :message.ParentId];
   }
   catch(Exception e) {}
```

Please provide me a solution asap ...

Comment: for future reference, the SFSE community does not look kindly on requests for assistance with imperatives like `asap`.  You should consider the community as providing a service on their own time - and, if you look at the historical record, will find that responses are timely without exhortation required.

Answer (score 6):

```
    //First you would loop through your EmailMessage list and collect ParentId to a Set.
Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
for(EmailMessage message : Messg){
   parentIds.add(message.ParentId);
}
//Then run the query
List<Case>cases = [SELECT id,RecordType.name, Description, AccountId, ContactId, OwnerId, CaseNumber, RecordTypeId, CountryCase__c, status, Origin, Subject, VIN__c, Device_Brand__c, Device_Type__c, Language__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :parentIds];
//Then you can loop through your cases to implement your logic
for(Case c : cases){
 //your logic goes here
}
```

Comment: @user20539 - Your request for an asap answer was granted, now can you please provide the same courtesy and accept the answer as the correct one.